# Find a closure of the set

Tags: general-topology

I have a set $$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}\mid x>0,y=\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\}$$
and I want to find a closure of this set. In the first place I thought, that the closure ($Cl(A)$) is equal to $X=A\cup\{(0,0)\}$, but I strongly doubt about this. I am absolutely sure that $X\subset Cl(A)$.

Could you give me any hints that will help me to come to the answer?

Comment: Have you looked at the graph of $y=\sin(1/x)$? In particular, note it "approaches" the segment $[-1,1]$ of the $y$-axis.

Comment: I know this is not your question, but note that this example is very well-known as it leads to the typical example of a connected space which is not arcwise connected. http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/TopologistsSineCurve.html

Comment: @David Mitra thx

Comment: @julien Thanks for your link, but what does you mean when you said that it is not my question? I found this question in my textbook.

Comment: Your question asks for closure and has nothing to do with connectedness. So my link does not help here, of course. But I thought you might wanted to know that this example comes around for other reasons.

Comment: @julien OK then, thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $(x,y) \in A$ consider the sequence $\{(x_n,y_n)\}\subset A$ with
$$
\frac{1}{x_n}=2n\pi +\frac{1}{x}.
$$
Since $y_n=\sin(x_n^{-1})=y$ for every $n$, we have $(x_n,y_n) \to (0,y) \in \{0\}\times[-1,1]$. Hence
$$
\{0\}\times[-1,1] \subset \text{Cl}(A).
$$
Conversely if $(x,y) \in \text{Cl}(A)$, then there exists some sequence $\{(x_n,y_n)\} \subset A$ such that $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$, in particular $x \ge 0$. If $x>0$ then $(x,y) \in A$, if not then $(x,y) \in \{0\}\times[-1,1]$. Thus $\text{Cl}(A)=A\cup\{0\}\times[-1,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for so detailed answer.